# Massive Reactivity lag in Meteor App on iOS

Tags: meteor

The following code is behaving correctly in Chrome and Safari on my MacBook and is reacting immediately. It causes a card to flip in the browser. However on iOS the card is flipping between 3 to 8 seconds after it is tapped.

Utterly perplexed. Could it be that the minimongo instance is just too much for the iPad's processor to handle well, this isn't a big dataset, there is one object with a few properties in the Deck collection and 20 objects with about 10 properties in the Cards collection. All properties are short strings (less than 30 characters). I wouldn't think this would load something with the processing capabilities of an iPad.

Also, I have a Galaxy Nexus and it runs without lag on it. Any solutions?

```
var flip = function (card) {
    var id = card;
    var state = Cards.findOne(id).state;
    if (state == 'flipped')
        Cards.update( id, {$set: {state: 'play'}});
    else
        Cards.update( id, {$set: {state: 'flipped'}});
};

Template.cards.events({
    'click .play': function (event) {
        flip(event.currentTarget.id);
    },
    'click .flipped': function (event) {
        flip(event.currentTarget.id);
    },
    'touchstart .play': function (event) {
        flip(event.currentTarget.id);
    },
    'touchstart .flipped': function (event) {
        flip(event.currentTarget.id);
    }
});

Template.cards.preserve({
  '.card[id]': function (node) { return node.id; },
  '.front[id]': function (node) { return node.id; },
  '.back[id]': function (node) { return node.id; },
  '.dummy[id]': function (node) { return node.id; },
});

Template.cards.cards = function () {
    var deck = Deck.findOne({ active: Session.get("activeDeck") });
    if ( deck != undefined )
        var cards = Cards.find({ deck_id: deck['_id'] }, {sort: {order: 1}}).fetch();
    else cards = {};
    return cards;
}

Template.cards.break = function () {
    return 12;
}

var Cards = new Meteor.Collection("cards");
var Deck = new Meteor.Collection("deck");

Meteor.subscribe("cards");
Meteor.subscribe("deck", function () {
    Session.set("activeDeck", 1);
});
```

Also, it is probably worth mentioning that on the page load there is a delay of roughly the same amount of time before any of the cards render at all.

UPDATE:
I've gotten into the Dev tools in safari and recorded a timeline for events and it's reporting the following for an event received from another client via the server, there is a similar profile for the client generated change, with more steps, but both feature a roughly 3 second pause after the first Timer Fire on deps.js line 55.
(0ms start time is logging as it should on the click or on the change from another client)

```
Type              | Details          | Location            | Start Time | Duration
Event Dispatched  | readystatechange | sockjs-0.3.4.js:791 | 0ms        | 0.0ms
Event Dispatched  | readystatechange | sockjs-0.3.4.js:791 | 0.5ms      | 7.4ms
Event Dispatched  | readystatechange | sockjs-0.3.4.js:791 | 9.0mms     | 1.0ms
Timer Fired       | 4801             | deps.js:55          | 12.1ms     | 927ms
Timer Fired       | 4803             | sockjs-0.3.4.js:848 | 4.18s      | 6.2ms
Timer Fired       | 4804             | deps.js:55          | 4.19s      | 0.0ms
```

Source is now available at: https://github.com/SnappyCroissant/memoryapp

Comment: Which ipad are you using for this test? Have you tried the ipad simulator in xcode?

Comment: I've tried an iPad 2 and an iPad 3 both running iOS 6.1. I haven't tried the simulator but I will look into it.

Comment: I've now tried it on an iPhone 4, also running iOS 6 and it took almost a minute to load and was completely unresponsive once it had. Something tells me that the javascript engine in mobile safari is struggling with the weight of Meteor.

Comment: Our app has 100kb of minified Javascript and it works fine on iOS, so I don't think it is a platform compatibility issue. Is there anything else different about your iOS test bed? VPN? Cell connection? Is it hosted on meteor.com so someone else can test it?

Comment: In my experience js apps and transitions in these apps always come out smoother on iOS relative to other platforms, could you test latency between your iOS device the place your server is hosted? Also one odd scenario, If you're using WiFi in a crowded/multistorey building it could also be due to congestion.

Comment: It's currently just running on my local machine and I'm accessing it over the local network. I just deployed to memoryapp.meteor.com so other people can test it. Edit: realised I haven't loaded the data into it yet, it will be ready shortly.

Comment: It's now live on memoryapp.meteor.com

Comment: I have a terrible internet connection but I can definitely see what you mean, what's causing it for me is the massive size of the pictures, I also experience it in Chrome on a very capable computer. Could you swap them out for small dummy pictures and see if theres a difference?

Comment: I didn't even consider that. Give me a minute.

Comment: Smaller images are up, no change with the lag but the transitions render much nicer.

Comment: Its slightly improved on my end except the click lag and the initial lag. I notice all the cards are redrawn on a click of a single one. If you're using handlebars in the style {{#each}} consider putting the stuff in the each block in another template so only that portion re-renders

Comment: I've been trying to get my head around how meteor decides what to re-render, I have a template 'cards' which has {{#each}} calling a template 'card'. This sounds like what you're describing but it still re-renders every card. Is it because I get all the cards from the database in one query?

Comment: Here's a git of the project: https://github.com/SnappyCroissant/memoryapp

It's quite chaotically coded I'm still getting my head around Meteor. Quite possible there is a fatal flaw somewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22647/discussion-between-tim-hope-and-akshat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be due to the fact the entire `DOM` was being redrawn (as pointed out by @Akshat in the comments above) as I passed an array rather than a cursor to the Handlebars `{{#each}}` loop as discovered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307612/981731